# git hangs on executing remote commands over ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

When I am trying to execute any remote command with git on windows (push, pull, clone) over ssh connection is stuck.
Authentication is successful but git is stuck on this line:

> debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0

I tried replacing ssh keys and reinstalling git. This was working previously but stopped suddenly.

Logs after authentication:
Authenticated to address ([address]:7300).

```
> debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
> debug1: channel 0: new [client-session] debug3: ssh_session2_open:
> channel_new: 0 debug2: channel 0: send open debug3: send packet: type
> 90 debug1: Entering interactive session. debug1: pledge: network
> debug3: receive packet: type 91 debug2:
> channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start debug2: fd
> 3 setting TCP_NODELAY debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20
> debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0 debug1: Sending command:
> git-receive-pack '(pack_name' debug2: channel 0: request exec
> confirm 1 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug2:
> channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done debug2:
> channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768 debug3: receive
> packet: type 99 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
> debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by restarting bitbucket server.